# Android - start intent with different layout

Tags: android, layout, android-intent

I have button and onClick I perform opening of a new activity like this:

```
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(myIntent1);
```

is there any way in this step to attach to newly opened activity layout I want? B class would be used a lot in my app and for each instance I need to have separate XML layout

Thanks for reply

Hmyzak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the ID of the layout you want via extra

Something like this:

```
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, B.class);
myIntent1.putExtra("layout", R.layout.myLayout);
startActivity(myIntent1);
```

Then in the Activity have this:

```
Bundle parameters = getIntent().getExtras();
if(parameters != null && parameters.containsKey("layout"))
   setContentView(parameters.getInt("layout"));
else
   setContentView(R.layout.defaultLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

pass condition `variable` thru `intent` and on `activity` set layout as per your variable value...